# Error response from daemon: container is not running?

Tags: docker

I am getting an error message 'Error from daemon: container is not running". Why? I started the container in detached mode, so it should be running? I tried the -it flags for interactivity but that did not work. I also tried sleeping docker but that did not work.

```
 sh "docker run -d --name mongocontainer19" 
 sh "docker exec mongocontainer19 mongo mongodump"
```

Answer (score 0):

The --name gives container names, which is mongocontainer19 in your case. So, you didn't put the image name there.

The syntax is
`$ docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE`
So the command should be like`$ docker run -d --name mongocontainer19 MyRedisIMAGE`

`--name <Your_container_alias>` will be considered as an option of the command. `-d` or `-p xx:xx` are options as well.